# Every element of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ for an $\alpha$ algebraic

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, extension-field

So I am stumped by the following problem:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be an algebraic number of degree $d$. We denote by $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of real numbers that can be written as: $$a_0 + a_1\alpha +\dots+ a_{d-1}\alpha^{d-1}$$
for some rational numbers $a_0, ... ,a_{d-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Show that every element $\gamma \in \mathbb{Q[\alpha]}$ is algebraic.

Does anyone have any pointers? I know the definition of an algebraic number.

Comment: Also I have absolutely no idea how to title this question. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about: "Every element of $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$ for $\alpha$ algebraic" ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\mathbb Q[\gamma]$ is a subspace of $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$. What can you conclude about
$$\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q[\gamma] \,?$$